# Why can't I use $lookup?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, aggregation-framework, lookup

I am trying to use the `$lookup` aggregate stage in meteor mongo using [aggregate](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-aggregate/blob/master/index.js) and [reactive-aggregate](https://atmospherejs.com/jcbernack/reactive-aggregate). Unfortunately I am getting this error.

> Exception from sub Feed id H3yhzuXdAk6LuQa7h MongoError: exception:
>   Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$lookUp'

I know I am not the only one struggling here based on the meteor blogs, https://forums.meteor.com/t/new-mongodb-lookup-aggregation-operator-in-3-2/6784, so any inputs ideas, workarounds but most particularly working source examples of reactive aggregates with `$lookup` would be great.

Edit: Alright so I start my meteor app by clicking test.bat

```
cd "."
start myDb.bat
start dbShell.bat
%MONGO_URL%=mongodb://localhost:27017/common
start met.bat
start "google chrome" http://localhost:3000
```

mydb.bat

```
mongod
```

met.bat

```
meteor
```

bdShell.bat

```
mongo
```

link.bat

```
start "google chrome" http://localhost:3000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that meteor's default mongo is pinned at 2.6.7 (at 1.3 version meteor).

Set your mongo url to a 3.2 database to use lookup

```
$ MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost/meteor meteor
```

(where mongo url points to a 3.2 db)

Comment: You sure that's not URI ?

Comment: it's `process.env.MONGO_URL`, done it a few times to use mongo@3.2

Comment: Ok so why aren't the script's I'm using getting me there on windows?

Comment: try using `set` for windows to set the environment variable

Comment: No dice mongo is still just waiting for connections of port 2017

Comment: 2017? Do you mean to use the default, `27017`?

Comment: As in the actual post yes.

Comment: Meteor 1.4 uses locally Mongo 3.2.6