# How to aggregate in meteor with $lookup

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, aggregation-framework

i have two collection. Main_Category or Sub_Category. i want to aggregate in meteor

```
//Main_Category document
{
   "_id" : "Jqcmc9sMHHN3qpJB7",
   "name" : "ahskdhkj",
   "icon_image" : "nbdenck",
   "description" : "jksdfhkj"
}


//Sub_Category document
{
  "_id" : "smjySSxboeGpY8Drn",
  "name" : "sub1",       
  "icon_image" : "nbdenck",
  "main_category_id" : "Jqcmc9sMHHN3qpJB7"
 }



var pipeline = [{
        $lookup: {
            from: "Sub_Category",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "main_category_id",
            as: "subcategory"
        }
    }];
    var data = Main_Category.aggregate(pipeline)
```

i also try this with meteorhacks:aggregate package . error msg is 
Error: exception: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$lookup'

```
   var pipeline = [{
        $lookup: {
            from: "Sub_Category",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "main_category_id",
            as: "subcategory"
        }
    }];
    var data = Main_Category.aggregate(pipeline)
```

Comment: Can this help? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37122518/why-cant-i-use-lookup

Comment: Are you using mongodb server 3.2?